# Get hidden field values from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-input

I am trying to assign hiddenfield values as shown on my page_load:

```
If Session("tempDir") Is Nothing Then
    If Request.Files.Count > 0 Then
        Dim tempDir As String
        tempDir = Path.GetRandomFileName()
        tempDir = tempDir.Substring(0, tempDir.LastIndexOf("."))
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" & tempDir))
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/" & tempDir))
        Session.Add("tempDir", tempDir)


        currentDirectory.Value = Session("tempDir").ToString

        Dim chunk As Integer = If(Context.Request("chunk") IsNot Nothing, Integer.Parse(Context.Request("chunk")), 0)
        Dim fileName As String = If(Context.Request("name") IsNot Nothing, Context.Request("name"), String.Empty)
        myfilename = fileName
        Session.Add("filename", myfilename)
        finalfilename.Value = currentDirectory.Value & fileName

        finalfilename.Value = Session("filename").ToString
        MsgBox(finalfilename.Value)

        workingDir.Value = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" & tempDir)
        Session.Add("tempDir", workingDir.Value)
        MsgBox(workingDir.Value)


        waitFlag.Value = "True"
        Session.Add("flag", waitFlag.Value)

        waitFlag.Value = Session("flag").ToString
        MsgBox(waitFlag.Value)

        Dim fileUpload As HttpPostedFile = Context.Request.Files(0)

        Dim uploadPath = Context.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" & tempDir)
        Using fs = New FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName), If(chunk = 0, FileMode.Create, FileMode.Append))
            Dim buffer = New Byte(fileUpload.InputStream.Length - 1) {}
            fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        End Using
    End If
End If
```

These are my html input hidden fields:

```
<input type="hidden" id="workingDir" runat="server"/>
<input type="hidden" id="finalfilename" runat="server"/>
<input type="hidden" id="waitFlag"  runat="server"/>
<input id="currentDirectory" type="hidden" runat="server"/>
```

This is my ajax call where I get all the hidden field values as undefined:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#btnconvert').click(function () {
         var wd = $('#workingDir').val();
         alert(wd);
         var fn = $('#finalfilename').val();
         alert(fn);
         var bf = $('#waitFlag').val();
         alert(bf);
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "Default.aspx/ProcessFiles",
             data: "{'workingDir':'" + wd + "', 'finalfilename':'" + fn + "', 'waitFlag':'" + bf + "'}",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                 alert("success");
             },
             error: function (data) {
                 alert("fail");
             }
         });
     });
  </script>
```

can anyone point out me where am I going wrong ?

Comment: did you check that its going into the if part because you have checked whether session is available then only it will assign values to hidden variables. Also are you using autopostback check or not?

Comment: Yes checked it as it's generating a session variable and storing the file in it so obviously it should have the filename right ?

Comment: Yes, Did you check via debugging whether this values are putted in hidden fields from server side code? Is there any possibility of not putting values.

Comment: have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You made some minor mistake.

The issue is with your Jquery button click event where you retrieve values from hidden field. Your hidden fields are server side control. So when it will be rendered, id of the hidden field will not be only **workingDir, finalfilename, waitFlag**

So you should use **ClientID** to get the values from **Hidden Field** as mentioned below :

```
var wd = $('#<%=workingDir.ClientID%>').val();
alert(wd);
var fn = $('#<%=finalfilename.ClientID%>').val();
alert(fn);
var bf = $('#<%=waitFlag.ClientID%>').val();
alert(bf);
```

Your JQUERY will look like as mentioned below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btnconvert').click(function () {
            var wd = $('#<%=workingDir.ClientID%>').val();
            alert(wd);
            var fn = $('#<%=finalfilename.ClientID%>').val();
            alert(fn);
            var bf = $('#<%=waitFlag.ClientID%>').val();
            alert(bf);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/ProcessFiles",
                data: "{'workingDir':'" + wd + "', 'finalfilename':'" + fn + "', 'waitFlag':'" + bf + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: @SpiderCode-Thanks for your reply..Now with your code I get ajax call success but still not getting any values for hidden fields.

Comment: can you check by putting : **alert(document.getElementById('<%=workingDir.ClientID%>').value);**

Comment: its the same and I dont think this is the prob might be in page_load while saving them to hiddenfields and on postback they are disppearing

Comment: and do you get the assigned value in **MsgBox(workingDir.Value)**